# Can I continue an interrupted partition move?

Tags: gparted, testdisk

I forgot to plug a charger to my laptop before starting the parition moving process. The partition I tried to move was 97 GB. It was almost at 80% and then the laptop powered down. Testdisk didn't give me options to recover the partition, so I just started installing Windows in the old position of the partition. How fucked am I?

Edit: It seems most of the data is fine. I tested 5 files and all of them were perfectly intact. Running a disk check on the partition results in a success with no errors. So I got lucky.

Comment: Entirely? However, provided those 80% were really moved, you’ll probably get good results with tools like PhotoRec (don’t mind the name).

Comment: If you don't need the data on the disk, I would suggest to reformat the disk and start from zero. (I hope you did take backups before launching on such a dangerous operation.)

Comment: I have doubts about the validity of your new findings, sorry. For me, it doesn’t add up. You said you performed an overlapping move that was _not finished_. Now of course it depends: If you moved the partition “left”, you could indeed be lucky and only unused space remained. However, if you moved it “right”, there’s no way it’s fine now. And, you installed Windows… where exactly? If possible please provide a rough overview of the old and new partition table. You did use `chkdsk /r`, right?

Comment: @DanielB Yes, I was moving the partition to the left. Only 50-60% of it was used. I got lucky.

Partitions before: `[ partition 1 (~25 MB) ] ; [ partition 2 (97 GB) ] ; [ partition 3 ]`.
Partitions after: `[ partition 2 (97 GB) ] ; [ partition 1 (~25 MB) ] ; [ partition 3 ]`

I performed a disk check in Linux using ntfsfix. This installation wasn't for me, it was for someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether the move was overlapping or not.

Non-overlapping moves are not a problem. In computers, nothing is actually moved – "move" is really just a **copy** + delete (where "delete" really means "remove from partition table) – so if the copy was interrupted, the original is still intact and there's no requirement to resume, you can just restart from the beginning.

Overlapping moves are a problem, because the process gradually *overwrites* the original with the shifted copy. (It depends on move direction and on how smart the program was, but eventually it'll start overwriting anyway.) Even if enough of the original is intact that you could mount it and see files, it's possible that sectors belonging to those files have already been overwritten with different data. In theory, an overlapping move would be perfectly resumable... as long as you knew where to resume it from. GParted doesn't store resumption data on disk, unfortunately, so if a GParted overlapping move gets interrupted then it'll require file recovery. (Most files should be recoverable, though.)

Comment: My move was overlapping, but most of my files are intact. I did a filesystem check and it seems that there are no issues with the filesystem. I could open most of the media files on the drive, and they worked just fine.

Comment: @RadoslavL If so backup what you can and start over.